# Unity - can't get reflective glass with orthographic camera?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, shader

I've tried Fantastic glass from the asset store along with just making glass myself:

[image]

And because the orthographic cam doesn't support deferred, or potentially due to other reasons, I cant get reflective glass despite having smoothness set to 1.

How can I get reflective glass in isometric?
[image]

Comment: which of those objects has the glass material? Note that it depends also on your lights ... and than having metallics on a flat surface like a plane does almost nothing .. it is more notcable on round surfaces

Comment: @derHugo the blue thing has glass. Even panning around though and moving lights there is no reflection

Comment: Have you tried placing a reflection probe in your scene and baking it? Or just using a static cubemap for it?

Comment: @KalleHalvarsson I did that and clicked bake on the probe, but nothing. Is there something Im missing?

Comment: Make sure that the bounds of the reflection probe encompasses the building. Try increasing them to 100x100x100 or something.

Answer (score 0):

I think i know what the issue might be here.

In deferred rendering, reflections are sometimes calculated by raycasting against a pixel in the normal buffer and see if any other pixel on the screen would be seen in the reflection (screen-space reflections).  For forward rendering, only reflection probes are used, which have to be baked at some point. Anything that is to be baked into a reflection probe needs to have "reflection probe static" set under its static flags - otherwise, only the skybox will render.

[image]

In your case, the background looks pitch black - so if you were to bake a probe without any other objects visible, the reflection probe would also turn out black and no reflections would be visible.

If this is a builder game, then this might be problematic since the environment is not static, though i guess you could set all the structures to "lightmap static" in their prefabs, and then have a real-time reflection probe which is set to update from script, and render it ever time the scene is updated. In that case, you might want to set it to a low resolution to avoid hiccups. If you want more accurate reflections, you can spread some probes out in a grid with slightly overlapping bounds, and only update the closest one.